# Liferay 7 Como solucionar NoClassDefFoundError BaseBodyTagSupport en portlet

Tags: java, eclipse

Como soluciono error que arroja al entrar modo edición en un portlet implementado en liferay 7.

Estoy importando las librerías que muestro en el código, pero al parecer revienta en `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>`.

Muestro código del Archivo **`edit.jsp`** el cual ya esta configurado en el **`web.xml`**.

```
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.RenderRequest"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.RenderResponse"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
<%@ page import="net.grupobit.Guardar"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.taglib.BaseBodyTagSupport"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %> 


<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL var="actionURL" />
```

El error que arroja el log de **`catalina.out`** es el siguiente:

> 2021-09-03 16:56:03.612 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-68][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:304] Unable to dispatch request: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib/BaseBodyTagSupport
> 2021-09-03 16:56:03.613 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-68][PortletServlet:119]  javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib/BaseBodyTagSupport
> javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib/BaseBodyTagSupport
> at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:307)
> at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:131)
>
> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib/BaseBodyTagSupport

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné actualizando las librerías util*.jar de mi proyecto.